# How do simulate a class of 100 students?

Tags: r

An exam with 20 multiple choice question with P=0.25 how do I simulate a class of 100 students and what is the average of the class of students. If the class is increased to 1000 what happens to the average?

I'm not sure where to begin. Other than just try to solving this manually.

```
n_experiments<-100
n_samples<-c(1:20)
means_of_sample_n<-c()

hist(rbinom( n = 100, size = 20, prob = 0.25 ))
```

I'm not sure what to do after this?

Comment: your `rbinom` line is simulating the "class" isn't it?  you can easily calculate the mean and variance of the class analytically if you want, checking it does the right thing with simulation can be useful (especially as a sanity check)

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to find a way to set the probability of answering correctly to 0.25, you can do that easily with the generation of a uniform distribution

```
n_experiments<-100
n_samples<-c(1:20)
means_of_sample_n<-c()

hist(rbinom( n = 100000, size = 20, prob = 0.25 ))


Nstu=100000
Nquest=20

Results=matrix(as.numeric(runif(100000*20)<0.25),ncol=20)

hist(apply(Results,1,sum))
mean(apply(Results,1,sum))
```

Answer (score 0):

from the definition of the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution):

- the mean is defined to be `n*p`, so `mu = 20*0.25`, giving a mean of 5.  this is independent of the class size
- the variance is defined to be `n*p*(1-p)`, and the standard deviation is the usual `sqrt` of this, so `sigma = sqrt(20*0.25*0.75)`, i.e. ~1.94.
- the [standard error of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) is `sigma / sqrt(k)`, where `k` would be your class size.  so we get SEMs of 0.19 and 0.061 for class sizes of 100 and 1000 respectively

it's often useful to check things via simulation, and we can simulate a single class as you were doing.

```
x <- rbinom(100, 20, 0.25)
plot(table(x))
```

I'm using `plot(table(x))` above instead of using `hist`, because this is a discrete distribution.  `hist` is more suited to continuous distributions, while `table` is better for discrete distributions with a small number of distinct values.

next, we can simulate things many times using `replicate`. in this case you're after the mean of the binomial draw:

```
y <- replicate(1000, mean(rbinom(100, 20, 0.25)))
c(mu=mean(y), se=sd(y))
```

which happened to give me `mu=5.002` and `se=0.201`, but will change every run.  increasing the class size to 1000, I get `mu=5.002` again, and `se=0.060`.  because these are random samples from the distribution they are subject to "monte-carlo error" but given enough replicates they should approach the analytical answers above.  that said, they're close enough to the analytical results to give me confidence I've not made any silly typos